# has_many :through association returns empty array on one side and filled array on the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relative simple app in which a couple of categories exist and a request is made. A request is put into one or more categories.

When I add a request with one or more categories I can easily show them to the user via `@request.categories`.

But whenever I try to show all the requests in a single category via `@category.requests` I get an empty array(as inspected: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Now my Rails is very rusty, so I might be doing something wrong. So here are my models:

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :requests, :through => :categories_requests
    has_many :categories_requests
end
```

**request.rb**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories, :through => :categories_requests
    has_many :categories_requests
end
```

**categories_request.rb**

```
class CategoriesRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :request
    belongs_to :category
end
```

So in short: How do I get all the requests for category 1 for example in a list in my category's `show`?

Comment: Wrong suggested tag apparently, woops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer may be as simple as to just invert the order of the requests

from:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :requests, :through => :categories_requests
    has_many :categories_requests
end
```

to

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categories_requests
    has_many :requests, :through => :categories_requests
end
```

Comment: It really was THAT easy... Weird that my request model did not fail but the category did, huh? Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) glad that I could help :)